# Passing Custom Model into View Rendering

Tags: presentation

I am calling a controller action from a form post, fetching all the data inside the controller and passing the model inside View Rendering, but Im getting null values inside the View.

I have used this [link](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/en/use-mvc-models.html), to Model type inside my CMS. Screenshot below:
[image]

**Controller Code:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<SearchResultItem> data = null;
    Item item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(new ID("{EEE7110D-6A46-4A20-B6EB-60FAC94B42D2}"));
    var resultSet = new EventSearchList();
    using (var context = ContentSearchManager.CreateSearchContext(new SitecoreIndexableItem(item)))
    {
        var query = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(x => x.Content.Contains("Sitecore PowerShell Extensions"));
        var results = query.GetResults();
        if (results != null && results.TotalSearchResults > 0)
        {
            data = results.Hits.Where(i => i.Document != null).Select(i => i.Document);
            

            foreach (var items in data)
            {
                var resultItem = items.GetItem();
                var eventSearchItem = new EventSearchItem()
                {
                    Title = resultItem.Fields["Title"].Value,
                    BodyCopy = resultItem.Fields["Body Copy"].Value
                };
                
                resultSet.eventSearchItems.Add(eventSearchItem);
            }
        }
    };
     var pathInfo = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(new ID("{E2C750EE-7F7D-4A9E-983E-8F04C8CC8B6B}")));
            return RedirectToRoute(Sitecore.Mvc.Configuration.MvcSettings.SitecoreRouteName, new { pathInfo = pathInfo.TrimStart(new char[] { '/' }), resultSet });
        }
    }
}
```

**View Model**

```
namespace Linde.Feature.Search.Models
{
     public class EventSearchList
     {
        public List<EventSearchItem> eventSearchItems = new List<EventSearchItem>();         
     }
}
```

**View:**

```
@using Sitecore.Mvc
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation
@model Linde.Feature.Search.Models.EventSearchList

@if (Model != null)
{
    <table>
    @foreach (var item in Model.eventSearchItems)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>Employee name:</td><td style="color:orange">@item.Title</td>
            <td>Years of work:</td><td style="color:orange">@item.BodyCopy</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
}
```

Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong here? Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `RedirectToRoute` works as standard HTTP GET with URL params appended by "?" to your URL, therefore, you can't pass complex models between your actions, only simple types.

I am not sure the exact context of the Index() action, is it possible to move the search logic to the other action instead and only pass the search parameter instead? I would recommend exploring the possibility of implementing the functionality of displaying the results using ajax, that way a redirect won't be necessary.

Otherwise in order to pass a list of complex objects like above you would need to use other solutions like MVC TempData, similar to how it is described in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789351/sharing-viewdata-across-actions-in-asp-net-mvc

Update:
Adding the retrieved model into Session does the work for now.

Comment: Hi Cristi, tried your last option, even with tempdata and viewdata, the model is not getting passed into the view. It is still null.

Comment: You could also use Cache/Session to pass data, but those need to be cleared afterwards. It is unclear for me why you would need to redirect. Instead of having a View Rendering you can just add another action in your Controller that handles the HTTPPost and will return a custom view with your model. You can take a look at the answer posted here https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7893/how-to-get-simple-form-post-to-work-in-sitecore-mvc-8-2

Comment: Im using Redirect to Route as I want the search results to be displayed in a new Sitecore Page(Item) with the search results. Working with session gives me the desired output and Im able to display it to my page. This is though not a standard practice, I need to modify the existing code.

@Cristi, it would help me immensely if you can throw some articles or links that can help me with a standard practice for implementing Search inside Sitecore 10.

And again thanks a log for your help.